# java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: gostR28147_cbc

Tags: java, rubygems

I am getting an error at `runtime java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: gostR28147_cbc` while integrating with GEM API. Please let me know what am I missing.I have included the below jars:

- aerogear-otp-java-1.0.0.m1.jar
- bcprov-jdk15on-1.52.jar
- bitcoinj-core-0.12
- core-1.52.0.0
- lcrypto-jdk16-143.jar
- sc-light-jdk15on-1.47.0.3
- scprov-jdk15on-1.47.0.2
- my-wallet-bitcoinj-0.6.1

Comment: Can you try clear all class file and compile all .class file again? btw if that doesn't work, can you pose the code yo are using?

Comment: Thanks Kun.After replacing round-java.jar with new build round-java.jar.its solved.

Comment: so it works, I'll put it on the Answer part so that more people can see it directly.

Answer (score 1):

You can try clear all class file and compile all .class file again.